# How to float elements side-by-side that go beyond page size?

Tags: html, css

I have run into a strange situation where I need to float two elements. The first is rather small around 250px. The second is large (800px), and creates horizontal scrollbars. I would like to float both of these elements so they are side-by-side, but the second gets pushed to its own line?

Is it possible to float two element side-by-side when they take up more than the page? I can't change the page size, or anything. I just want to know if this is possible and how.

Thanks

Comment: Can you define the parent's width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could float a 250px and 800px div inside a 1050px wide box.

```
<div style="width:1050px;">
    <div style="width:250px;float:left">left</div>
    <div style="width:800px;float:left">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a great simple technique. The only thing I had to change up was removing the second float element. The page I am working on is pretty messed up so it caused weird issues with that.

Answer (score 3):

You want to add:

```
overflow-x: scroll;
white-space: nowrap;
```

To your wrapping div around those two elements.

And add:

```
display: inline-block;
```

To the div's to be overflowed.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/P8YDC/2/)

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't work. The divs are block elements. Tested in FF.

Comment: @Marnix fixed - needed `display:inline-block;`

Comment: This kind of works, but the horizontal scrollbar is below the floated element, it's not on the browser. So to scroll horizontally you have to first scroll down a big list to get to those scrollbars

Comment: @chobo You can't move the scrollbar to the top in pure CSS but you can do it with JS: http://livepipe.net/control/scrollbar

Comment: I like this answer better. In the case I'm using it in, width of the children (and containing element) is variable